# Why the data from my object is not setting to my setState in my react class component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object, dom-events

```
class AreaChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      chartData: CHART_DATA,
      chartDataSelection: CHART_DATA.selection
    };}
```

My CHART_DATA is my object and I assigned it to chartData.
Below is my updateData function. This is where I am having a problem. Under this.setState, chartDataSelection is not grabbing the data from my object. I don't know how to properly grab the selection key from the CHART_DATA object. Below this code is the other js file that holds that object.

```
updateData(timeline) {
    this.setState({
      chartDataSelection: timeline
    });

    switch (timeline) {
      case "one_month":
        this.setState({
          options: {
            xaxis: {
              min: new Date("28 Jan 2013").getTime(),
              max: new Date("27 Feb 2013").getTime()
            }
          }
        });
        break;
      case "six_months":
        this.setState({
          options: {
            xaxis: {
              min: new Date("27 Sep 2012").getTime(),
              max: new Date("27 Feb 2013").getTime()
            }
          }
        });
        break;
      case "one_year":
        this.setState({
          options: {
            xaxis: {
              min: new Date("27 Feb 2012").getTime(),
              max: new Date("27 Feb 2013").getTime()
            }
          }
        });
        break;
      case "ytd":
        this.setState({
          options: {
            xaxis: {
              min: new Date("01 Jan 2013").getTime(),
              max: new Date("27 Feb 2013").getTime()
            }
          }
        });
        break;
      case "all":
        this.setState({
          options: {
            xaxis: {
              min: undefined,
              max: undefined
            }
          }
        });
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
```

CHART_DATA.js --- this data is for my Area Chart from ApexCharts

```
const CHART_DATA = {
  coins: "hello",
  isFetching: false,
  selection: "one_year", // this data is for the ReactApexChart line 14-395
  options: {
    annotations: {
      yaxis: [
        {
          y: 0,
          tickAmount: 0,
          borderColor: "transparent",
          label: {
            borderColor: "red",

            show: false,
            showAlways: false,

            style: {
              color: "#fff",
              background: "#00E396"
            }
          },
          floating: true,
          axisTicks: {
            show: false
          },
          axisBorder: {
            show: false
          },
          labels: {
            show: false
          },
          crosshairs: {
            show: false
          }
        }
      ],
      xaxis: [
        {
          x: new Date("14 Nov 2012").getTime(),
          borderColor: "transparent",
          yAxisIndex: 0,
          label: {
            show: false,
            text: "",
            style: {
              color: "#fff",
              background: "#775DD0"
            }
          },
          axisTicks: {
            show: false
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
      enabledOnSeries: false
    },
    markers: {
      size: 0,
      style: "hollow"
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: "datetime",
      min: new Date("01 Mar 2012").getTime(),
      tickAmount: 6
    },
    tooltip: {
      x: {
        format: "MMMM dd yyyy"
      }
    },
    fill: {
      type: "gradient",
      gradient: {
        shadeIntensity: 1,
        opacityFrom: 0.3,
        opacityTo: 0.9,
        stops: [0, 100]
      }
    },
    colors: ["#6433ff", "#00E396", "#CED4DC"],
    stroke: {
      width: "2"
    },

    chart: {
      toolbar: {
        show: false,
        tools: {
          download: true,
          selection: true,
          zoom: true,
          zoomin: true,
          zoomout: true,
          pan: true,
          reset: true | '<img src="/static/icons/reset.png" width="20">',
          customIcons: []
        },
        autoSelected: "zoom"
      }
    }
  },

  series: [
    {
      //timestamps for the areaChart
      data: [
        [1327359600000, 30.95],
        [1327446000000, 31.34],
        [1327532400000, 31.18],
        [1327618800000, 31.05],
        [1327878000000, 31.0],
        [1327964400000, 30.95],
        [1328050800000, 31.24],
        [1328137200000, 31.29],
        [1328223600000, 31.85],
        [1328482800000, 31.86],
        [1328569200000, 32.28],
        [1328655600000, 32.1],
        [1328742000000, 32.65],
        [1328828400000, 32.21],
        [1329087600000, 32.35],
        [1329174000000, 32.44],
        [1329260400000, 32.46],
        [1329346800000, 32.86],
        [1329433200000, 32.75],
        [1329778800000, 32.54],
        [1329865200000, 32.33],
        [1329951600000, 32.97],
        [1330038000000, 33.41],
        [1330297200000, 33.27],
        [1330383600000, 33.27],
        [1330470000000, 32.89],
        [1330556400000, 33.1],
        [1330642800000, 33.73],
        [1330902000000, 33.22],
        [1330988400000, 31.99],
        [1331074800000, 32.41],
        [1331161200000, 33.05],
        [1331247600000, 33.64],
        [1331506800000, 33.56],
        [1331593200000, 34.22],
        [1331679600000, 33.77],
        [1331766000000, 34.17],
        [1331852400000, 33.82],
        [1332111600000, 34.51],
        [1332198000000, 33.16],
        [1332284400000, 33.56],
        [1332370800000, 33.71],
        [1332457200000, 33.81],
        [1332712800000, 34.4],
        [1332799200000, 34.63],
        [1332885600000, 34.46],
        [1332972000000, 34.48],
        [1333058400000, 34.31],
        [1333317600000, 34.7],
        [1333404000000, 34.31],
        [1333490400000, 33.46],
        [1333576800000, 33.59],
        [1333922400000, 33.22],
        [1334008800000, 32.61],
        [1334095200000, 33.01],
        [1334181600000, 33.55],
        [1334268000000, 33.18],
        [1334527200000, 32.84],
        [1334613600000, 33.84],
        [1334700000000, 33.39],
        [1334786400000, 32.91],
        [1334872800000, 33.06],
        [1335132000000, 32.62],
        [1335218400000, 32.4],
        [1335304800000, 33.13],
        [1335391200000, 33.26],
        [1335477600000, 33.58],
        [1335736800000, 33.55],
        [1335823200000, 33.77],
        [1335909600000, 33.76],
        [1335996000000, 33.32],
        [1336082400000, 32.61],
        [1336341600000, 32.52],
        [1336428000000, 32.67],
        [1336514400000, 32.52],
        [1336600800000, 31.92],
        [1336687200000, 32.2],
        [1336946400000, 32.23],
        [1337032800000, 32.33],
        [1337119200000, 32.36],
        [1337205600000, 32.01],
        [1337292000000, 31.31],
        [1337551200000, 32.01],
        [1337637600000, 32.01],
        [1337724000000, 32.18],
        [1337810400000, 31.54],
        [1337896800000, 31.6],
        [1338242400000, 32.05],
        [1338328800000, 31.29],
        [1338415200000, 31.05],
        [1338501600000, 29.82],
        [1338760800000, 30.31],
        [1338847200000, 30.7],
        [1338933600000, 31.69],
        [1339020000000, 31.32],
        [1339106400000, 31.65],
        [1339365600000, 31.13],
        [1339452000000, 31.77],
        [1339538400000, 31.79],
        [1339624800000, 31.67],
        [1339711200000, 32.39],
        [1339970400000, 32.63],
        [1340056800000, 32.89],
        [1340143200000, 31.99],
        [1340229600000, 31.23],
        [1340316000000, 31.57],
        [1340575200000, 30.84],
        [1340661600000, 31.07],
        [1340748000000, 31.41],
        [1340834400000, 31.17],
        [1340920800000, 32.37],
        [1341180000000, 32.19],
        [1341266400000, 32.51],
        [1341439200000, 32.53],
        [1341525600000, 31.37],
        [1341784800000, 30.43],
        [1341871200000, 30.44],
        [1341957600000, 30.2],
        [1342044000000, 30.14],
        [1342130400000, 30.65],
        [1342389600000, 30.4],
        [1342476000000, 30.65],
        [1342562400000, 31.43],
        [1342648800000, 31.89],
        [1342735200000, 31.38],
        [1342994400000, 30.64],
        [1343080800000, 30.02],
        [1343167200000, 30.33],
        [1343253600000, 30.95],
        [1343340000000, 31.89],
        [1343599200000, 31.01],
        [1343685600000, 30.88],
        [1343772000000, 30.69],
        [1343858400000, 30.58],
        [1343944800000, 32.02],
        [1344204000000, 32.14],
        [1344290400000, 32.37],
        [1344376800000, 32.51],
        [1344463200000, 32.65],
        [1344549600000, 32.64],
        [1344808800000, 32.27],
        [1344895200000, 32.1],
        [1344981600000, 32.91],
        [1345068000000, 33.65],
        [1345154400000, 33.8],
        [1345413600000, 33.92],
        [1345500000000, 33.75],
        [1345586400000, 33.84],
        [1345672800000, 33.5],
        [1345759200000, 32.26],
        [1346018400000, 32.32],
        [1346104800000, 32.06],
        [1346191200000, 31.96],
        [1346277600000, 31.46],
        [1346364000000, 31.27],
        [1346709600000, 31.43],
        [1346796000000, 32.26],
        [1346882400000, 32.79],
        [1346968800000, 32.46],
        [1347228000000, 32.13],
        [1347314400000, 32.43],
        [1347400800000, 32.42],
        [1347487200000, 32.81],
        [1347573600000, 33.34],
        [1347832800000, 33.41],
        [1347919200000, 32.57],
        [1348005600000, 33.12],
        [1348092000000, 34.53],
        [1348178400000, 33.83],
        [1348437600000, 33.41],
        [1348524000000, 32.9],
        [1348610400000, 32.53],
        [1348696800000, 32.8],
        [1348783200000, 32.44],
        [1349042400000, 32.62],
        [1349128800000, 32.57],
        [1349215200000, 32.6],
        [1349301600000, 32.68],
        [1349388000000, 32.47],
        [1349647200000, 32.23],
        [1349733600000, 31.68],
        [1349820000000, 31.51],
        [1349906400000, 31.78],
        [1349992800000, 31.94],
        [1350252000000, 32.33],
        [1350338400000, 33.24],
        [1350424800000, 33.44],
        [1350511200000, 33.48],
        [1350597600000, 33.24],
        [1350856800000, 33.49],
        [1350943200000, 33.31],
        [1351029600000, 33.36],
        [1351116000000, 33.4],
        [1351202400000, 34.01],
        [1351638000000, 34.02],
        [1351724400000, 34.36],
        [1351810800000, 34.39],
        [1352070000000, 34.24],
        [1352156400000, 34.39],
        [1352242800000, 33.47],
        [1352329200000, 32.98],
        [1352415600000, 32.9],
        [1352674800000, 32.7],
        [1352761200000, 32.54],
        [1352847600000, 32.23],
        [1352934000000, 32.64],
        [1353020400000, 32.65],
        [1353279600000, 32.92],
        [1353366000000, 32.64],
        [1353452400000, 32.84],
        [1353625200000, 33.4],
        [1353884400000, 33.3],
        [1353970800000, 33.18],
        [1354057200000, 33.88],
        [1354143600000, 34.09],
        [1354230000000, 34.61],
        [1354489200000, 34.7],
        [1354575600000, 35.3],
        [1354662000000, 35.4],
        [1354748400000, 35.14],
        [1354834800000, 35.48],
        [1355094000000, 35.75],
        [1355180400000, 35.54],
        [1355266800000, 35.96],
        [1355353200000, 35.53],
        [1355439600000, 37.56],
        [1355698800000, 37.42],
        [1355785200000, 37.49],
        [1355871600000, 38.09],
        [1355958000000, 37.87],
        [1356044400000, 37.71],
        [1356303600000, 37.53],
        [1356476400000, 37.55],
        [1356562800000, 37.3],
        [1356649200000, 36.9],
        [1356908400000, 37.68],
        [1357081200000, 38.34],
        [1357167600000, 37.75],
        [1357254000000, 38.13],
        [1357513200000, 37.94],
        [1357599600000, 38.14],
        [1357686000000, 38.66],
        [1357772400000, 38.62],
        [1357858800000, 38.09],
        [1358118000000, 38.16],
        [1358204400000, 38.15],
        [1358290800000, 37.88],
        [1358377200000, 37.73],
        [1358463600000, 37.98],
        [1358809200000, 37.95],
        [1358895600000, 38.25],
        [1358982000000, 38.1],
        [1359068400000, 38.32],
        [1359327600000, 38.24],
        [1359414000000, 38.52],
        [1359500400000, 37.94],
        [1359586800000, 37.83],
        [1359673200000, 38.34],
        [1359932400000, 38.1],
        [1360018800000, 38.51],
        [1360105200000, 38.4],
        [1360191600000, 38.07],
        [1360278000000, 39.12],
        [1360537200000, 38.64],
        [1360623600000, 38.89],
        [1360710000000, 38.81],
        [1360796400000, 38.61],
        [1360882800000, 38.63],
        [1361228400000, 38.99],
        [1361314800000, 38.77],
        [1361401200000, 38.34],
        [1361487600000, 38.55],
        [1361746800000, 38.11],
        [1361833200000, 38.59],
        [1361919600000, 39.6]
      ]
    }
  ]
};

export default CHART_DATA;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't telling setState to update your chartData (setState{chartData: {updatedData}}) but creating a new state object called options. First you need modify the existing charData. In this case I've spread it out into a variable called data. Then you modify data with the new xaxis and then replace chartData completely with your updated object. I've shortened your switch just for the example but you will have to update each of them. I hope this helps.

```
updateData(timeline) {
    this.setState({
      chartDataSelection: timeline
    });


   let data = {...d}

    switch (timeline) {
      case "one_month":
       data.options.xaxis = {
              min: new Date("28 Jan 2013").getTime(),
              max: new Date("27 Feb 2013").getTime()
            }
        this.setState({chartData: data});
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Jonny for helping me out. It seems I got a parsing error: Unexpected token for declaring the data variable outside of the switch statement. I'm kinda confused by this error because this is still declared inside the class component.

Comment: @Will, It seems I forgot a let in front of data. It got confused because I was setting data as though it had already been declared even though it had not. Try again with that let in front of data.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I'm a lil confused. When you say try again with that let in front of data, what exactly do you mean in front of data? Thanks

Comment: @Will, Instead of  data = {...d} it should be let data = {...d}. let and var tell the parser that you are defining a variable rather than setting an existing variable. If let doesn't work try var instead. The fact you use it inside a switch might cause scoping issues with let. Hopefully, that clears it up. If not let me know.